# after upgrade on Windows 10 and first reboot, keyboard and touchpad doesn't works

Tags: drivers, keyboard, windows-10, touchpad

after upgrade my Notebook SAMSUNG NP-RF712S01IT Windows 10 works fine, but after first reboot the keyboard and trackpad doesn't works. On devices management, I find an unknown board (I think that it is the CHIPSET BOARD) and some errors on drivers keyboard and touchpad (register error code 19) and I am unable to use keyboard and touchpad.

I tried the following without success:

- disable and enable drivers
- find automatically new drivers
- reinstall drivers
- disable chipset board

Any suggestion to help my situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 uses a generic trackpad and keyboard drivers. To correct this follow these steps:

1. Download the latest touchpad & chipset drivers: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP-RF711-S01USoption=com_remository&Itemid=353&func=download&id=1675&chk=d3edc55ebf64cf59602143405e88c3de&no_html=1
2. Go to Device Manager and look for the touchpad
3. Right Click Update Driver Software > Browse My computer ... > Let me pick from a list
4. Unselect Show Incompatible Hardware
5. Find touchpad and keyboard and select the appropriate driver
6. To ensure changes to the driver do not occur without your knowledge, open the Control Panel (right-click Start button and select Control Panel)
7. Navigate to System and Security > System > Advanced system settings
8. Click Hardware tab > Device Installation Settings and select No, let me choose what to do option
9. Select Never install driver software from Windows Update

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact issue with Dell laptop with Windows 10 (build 1909)

## Steps to solve the issue:

1. Open Registry Editor: Start -> run -> `regedit`
2. Navigate to the following registry:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96B-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`
3. On the right side, double click `UpperFilter`
4. remove all values and keep only one line - `kbdclass` so that it would look like this:
   [image: registry editor after removing bad values]
5. Reboot your machine

## Warning

This might corrupt your keyboard driver within `VMWare` software.

## Note

Solution found in [this link](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/79862-keyboard-stopped-working-code-19-a.html)